# How to change the color of treeitem expand and collapse arrow in javafx?

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have got some trouble with treeitems of a treeview.
There are expand and collapse icon-arrows, when you have child-treeitems.
I only know how to change the background-color of this expand/collapse icons.
But I don't know how to change the color of the arrow.

```html
.tree-cell .tree-disclosure-node {
    -fx-background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

.tree-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node {
     -fx-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Is there any chance to change the color of this arrow? I don't want to use self drawing icons. I just want to change the color of the arrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to `TreeViewSkin`, the disclosure node is a `StackPane`, and has as a child another `StackPane` with style class `arrow`.

If you want to change the default color of this node, just add the color for the `arrow` class:

```
.tree-cell > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow  {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
.tree-cell:expanded > .tree-disclosure-node > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```